# Dynamic Time Warp with Speech Signal Processing Toolkit (SPTK) output

Tags: audio, dtw

I'm an IT student and got an assignment to do about Dynamic Time Warping(DTW)  using the Speech Signal Processing Toolkit (SPTK) and comparing some words spoken by 2 speakers and finding the similarities.
I managed to get the SPTK working and everything, collected 8 people(4 female, 4 male) who recorded 8 words each for me(same words for every person) and saved them as files with a .wav extension.

My .wav files are: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, mono 16000 Hz.
I transfered every .wav file into .short data files.
I transfered every .short file to a .mcep file with this line of code:

```
x2x +sf < source_maleA.short | frame -l 400 -p 80 | window -l 400 -L 512 | mcep -l 512 -m 20 -a 0.42 > source_maleA.mcep
```

After that, I went to compare the .mcep files with this line of code:

```
dtw -m 24 target_maleB.mcep < source_maleA.mcep > source_maleA_target_maleB.dtw
```

The output of that command line should be a numeric value(probably a float/double/int value) or a few values. The problem is that I'm not sure how to open that .dtw files and in the documentation I get there isn't any good info about that. When I try to open it in any editor or cat it in the terminal, I get some strange letters as an output [picture 1].

In the documentation however it says that with the parameter -s [Score] I can get the score of the DTW process. So I tried it with this command line:

```
dtw -m 24 -s Scorefile target_maleB.mcep < source_maleA.mcep > source_maleA_target_maleB.dtw
```

I get a value, but in strange format.

I searched online and in many documentations about the .dtw file and couldn't find anything. I tried to convert the result into another format, but not any luck with that.
Tried to contact my mentor about it, but no answers so far and it's been a while already.

Anyone could give me any suggestion on what to do or anything else?
The documentation can be found on this site : http://sp-tk.sourceforge.net/ (sorry for not link, but still not enough reputation - will remove if I have to), but I don't think it's needed that much, since I think I pretty much understood the DTW process and think I've done it ok, it's just that the output is causing me problems.

Thanks in advance,

Marco.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHBX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The score file is in float so you have to convert it to asci with the x2x command from SPTK:

x2x +fa scorefile.bin > scorefile.txt